# Android Samsung Galaxy s2 bluetooth-app-debugging with Eclipse without uninstalling at each launch

Tags: android, bluetooth, hardware, galaxy

I got a Samsung Gs2 to get data via bluetooth, the problem is that debugging has become tedious, because each time I launch the debugger I have to repeat all the steps in http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Do I really have to uninstall the app, do the bluetooth-pairing for the device etc... before I restart my eclipse debugger. Isn't there a way to do all the settings just on the first launch?

Comment: Interesting, I've got a similar problem. If I launch the debugger without changing code, it works OK. If I change code, I get a "Force Close" error when trying to receive any Bluetooth messages in my BroadcastReceiver. If I then launch the debugger again the BroadcastReceiver works OK. As you said, uninstalling the app each time avoids this problem. I think perhaps if the app unregistered the BroadcastReciver it may fix this, but I dont want to do that.

Comment: does it do the bluetooth pairing automatically or do you have to do it by hand every time?

Comment: My code starts Bluetooth discovery & then pairs with a specific device when it finds it. The problem I get is a Null Pointer Exception in the Bluetooth Discovery Broadcast Listener. If I change code & debug, the NPE happens - if I run again the Broadcast Listener runs OK. I suspect Android is having problems with the registration of the Broadcast Receiver once the code has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with the SSP stack in the current GS2 firmware.

I solved some issues by stopping and restarting the bluetooth.

see:
http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/firmware-problems/connection-problems-sgs-bluetooth-spp-device/